# How to clone a disk with laserlock protection?

Tags: compact-disc, disk-encryption, disk-cloning, copy-protection

I have a CD with [laserlock](http://laserlock.com/faq.html) protection. The disk is old and I want to make a backup. I use the disk for running a software, the disk needs to be inserted every time I launch the app. How can I clone the original disk or remove the encryption so that I can run the app without the disk? I've tried regular disk cloners (Alcohol, CdClone, DAEMON tools) but they didn't work. Please note that, I own the disk and will use the clone for personal uses only, nothing illegal.

Comment: Have you considered what you want simply is not possible?  The problem you face is the tools you want are very hard to find, because while its legal to do what you want ( i.e. make a personal backup ), the laws basically make it not possible to distrubute the software that allows you to do so ( its not legal to write software that disables or removes the DRM protection ).  I assume getting a copy from the distributor isn't an option?

Comment: The issue is that I can't find a distributor... I bought the disk back in 2009.

Comment: Based on my limited ability to research the DRM in question.  It really does look like `Daemon Tools` should allow to enable LaserLock emulation.  Of course that feature might have been discontinued since 2011.

Comment: The following thread has some suggestions you should try.  http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/f19/unable-emulate-laserlock-disk-29661/